# How to add interceptor for spring boot logging in application.yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, https

My project has an custom HttpInterceptor interface which can be implemented for intercepting logs.

```
public interface HttpInterceptor {

 
    default String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

   
    default boolean isEnabled() {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

   
    default boolean validate(HttpExchange exchange) {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

  
    default HttpExchange postHandle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        return exchange;
    }

    default HttpExchange afterCompletion(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        return exchange;
    }

    default HttpExchange preHandle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        return exchange;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a class which implements the above interceptor using below code.

```
public class Registrator implements HttpInterceptor {

   

    @Override
    public HttpExchange preHandle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {        
         log.info("Getting intercepted for all Http calls");      

        return exchange;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpExchange afterCompletion(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        log.debug("Removing VIN from MDC");
      
    }
}
```

I am struggling to get this interceptor print the log in my application for any HttpCalls.

What should be added in my application.yml file to let springboot know that use this interceptor for logging ?
How to set logging level interceptor in application.yml ?

logging:
level: ??

Answer (score 0):

The logs level in the application.yml can be set like this for the whole app and then overwrite for specific class or package.

```
**application.yml**
logging.level.root=INFO // just as an example for whole app. you can select a specific class or package.
logging.level.{yourpackage}.Registrator=INFO  // DEBUG, FATAL




package {yourpackage}
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Registrator implements HttpInterceptor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Registrator.class);
```

I am using org.slf4j.Logger, org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

And in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
```